# IE11 Ajax Request Only Made if Dev Tools Open

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, internet-explorer-11

I have an asp.net MVC5 app using knockoutjs for the views.

I have a problem with the "Refresh" button on the following page:

[image: summarypage]

The button click is bound to the following ajax request:

```
self.get = function () {
        $loadingIndicator.show();

        $.ajax({
            url: BASE_URL + 'APInvoicesSummary/GetRecords',
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                'cache': false,
                'page': self.pagingOptions.currentPage(),
                'pageSize': self.pagingOptions.pageSize(),
                'filter': self.filterOptions.filterText == undefined ? '' : self.filterOptions.filterText(),
                'sort': self.sortInfo().column.field + ' ' + self.sortInfo().direction
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                self.pagingOptions.totalServerItems(data.RecCount);

                var recsArray = [];
                $.each(data.PageOfRecords, function (key, value) {
                    recsArray.push(
                        new rec(
                            moment(value.DateReceived).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm ss'),
                            value.BatchRef,
                            value.Control_NumOfItems,
                            Math.round(value.Control_Value * 100) / 100,
                            value.Control_LinkToArchive,
                            value.Rejected_NumOfItems,
                            value.Rejected_Value,
                            value.Accepted_NumOfItems,
                            Math.round(value.Accepted_Value *100) / 100,
                            value.RejectedLineNumbers,
                            value.LinkToEditBatch
                            )
                    );
                });
                self.recs(recsArray);
            }
        });
```

Here is the binding:

```
<div id="Refresh">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md refresh-button" data-bind="click: get">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span> Refresh
    </button>
</div>
```

Everything works fine with Chrome but when running in IE11, clicking the button has no effect unless the F12 Dev Tools are open - then it works ok. I can see in fiddler that without Dev Tools being open, no requests are made.

Any Ideas?

I've read elsewhere that this can be down to console.log code in the javascript  but I've done a search and can find none.

Comment: IE has the nasty habit of caching AJAX GET requests aggressively. Try using POST, or use a cache-busting technique (like appending the current timestamp to the URL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following custom ActionFilterAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I then decorated the controller class that contains the action my KnockoutJS was making an Ajax call to:

```
[NoCache]
public class APInvoicesSummaryController : APInvoicesBaseController
{
```

Comment: That's the proper solution.